# acf_form not publishing fields in a CPT

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

If I set post-status to 'publish' (as shown below) this form creates the post, but my acf fields for this post type (some should be auto-populated) aren't added to the database

If I set post-status to 'draft' this form creates the draft - if I edit and save that draft all is good

Any ideas?

Thanks, Richard

```
<?php acf_form_head(); ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="primary" class="rs-add-forms">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php acf_form(array(
        'post_id'       => 'new_post',
        'post_title' => true,
        'new_post'      => array(
            'post_type'     => 'people',
            'post_status'   => 'publish'
        ),
        'fields' => array('field_5ed5c2215be79',), 
        'submit_value'  => 'Create Person',
        'html_submit_button'  => '<input type="submit" class="rs-add-button" value="%s" />',
        
        'updated_message' => false
    )); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `acf_form` calls [`acf_add_local_field`](https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/blob/ef5555c494baca8709aae0f718cb2e78b39025e7/includes/forms/form-front.php#L223) on the value of the `fields` key in the options array, you should try structuring your data [like the function parses defaults for, internally](https://github.com/AdvancedCustomFields/acf/blob/3247713b06123f11c3478141beebfc6a23f41417/includes/local-fields.php#L342).

```
// Apply default properties needed for import.
$field = wp_parse_args($field, array(
    'key'       => '',
    'name'      => '',
    'type'      => '',
    'parent'    => '',
));
```

Therefore, you might modify to

```
'fields' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'field_5ed5c2215be79',
        'name' => 'Form Field Title',
        'type' => 'registered_acf_fieldtype',
        'parent' => '[probably optional]'
    )
),
```

Comment: Thanks Cameron, That sounds promising, but I'm confused by the arrays ```'fields' => array('field_5ed5c2215be79',),``` is an array of different fields, but you're showing it as an array of different elements for one field

Comment: This makes sense, except I have fields that need to be "initialized" but I don't want them showing in the form. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: hidden input type, no?